# Can we use MongoDB with ORMs we used to use with relational databases, such as linq2sql, entity framework, subsonic,...?

Tags: .net, mongodb, orm, database, nosql

I want to know if its possible based on your experience to use our previous experiences using .net ORMs with nosql db such as MongoDB.
And also if you know samples doing this please refer in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reuse your LINQ skills because the two providers between .net and MongoDB support LINQ. Both the norm driver and the mongodb-csharp-driver support LINQ queries.

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/C+Sharp+Language+Center

Mapping an object to a document is most of the time easier than mapping an object to a set of tables. But you can't reuse all your previous experiences because a document db and a relational db are very different. But isn't it fun to explore a new "world"?